# What exactly are resource leaks?

Tags: java, resources

I have heard people many times use the term "Resource leak". I'm sure this is a global phenomenon, though for the purpose of this answer, I will stick to those in Java. Take for example the following code :

```
public void append(String text) throws IOException
{
    BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("tf2rocks.imnotkidding", true));
    buffWriter.write(event);
    buffWriter.close();
}
```

In the above snippet, there is a resource leak, as if an `IOException` was thrown by `write()`, `close()` will never be called.

Now my question is : What exactly is a resource leak? How can they cause harm to me?

If each java program is executed in it's own instance of the JVM, in an enclosed environment, how exactly can these "resource leaks" cause me harm? Is it possible for other malicious programs to take advantage of this?

Comment: All you need to do is understand `close()`. I think the main issue is that you can only use a finite number of file descriptors.

Comment: @keyser So if I keep causing these 'leaks', will I eventually not be able to open files in Windows any more?

Comment: I am amazed that someone who knows how to use a computer can't work out why it would be bad if your program endlessly uses resources until they run out.  BTW not calling close() doesn't result in a resource leak in this instance.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I was actually asking about the security implications, not resource limitations. Also, what?? There's no resource leak in this case? Thats confusing..

Comment: @Hele why would a resource leak result in a security problem given Java lazily cleans up objects by default. Whether you close the file or not, it will be closed when the object is GCed. The reason you call close() is to ensure the buffer is written determistically rather than written randomly on a GC or potentially lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes implementing `java.io.Closeable` (since JDK 1.5) and `java.lang.AutoCloseable` (since JDK 1.7) are considered to represent external resources, which should be closed using method close(), when they are no longer needed. All operating system have limits on the number of sockets, file handles.etc. that can be opened at particular instance of time. If you don't close the resources then you are unnecessary keeping them open and if you continue to keep opening more and more resources without closing them then after some time operating system will not be able to allocate more resources.

Comment: At the end of execution of a java program, will these "leaks" be fixed by the JVM?

Comment: @Hele , No until unless the process will not be killed.

Answer (score 0):

You are right with your example. Think from OS perspective, where you have predefined file/sockets handles that you could create i.e. say this many files can be open at a time. Now if you keep on opening multiple files, you may go out of number of files that can be open.

So although, its JVM but JVM alone can't run without the help from OS. File handler/descriptor is just one of the example.

If it's memory, then you don't have you worry as it will be handled by GC automatically but GC wont take care of resources.

Comment: At the end of execution of a java program, will these "leaks" be fixed by the JVM?

Comment: process will be killed so will be reclaimed.